# spring-data-neo4j not using workspace directory for storeDirectory

Tags: eclipse, macos, neo4j, spring-data-graph, spring-data-neo4j

My different example projects are working well, but the database is stored in my Eclipse application itself. I am using Eclipse on OSX, so are there any known problems? Did anyone have the same problem so far?

I did specify the path with:

```
<neo4j:config storeDirectory="target/neo.db" />
```

Comment: what happens if you specify it that way?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Have you tried setting an absolute location like /tmp/mydb
?

Comment: Yeah I solved it with setting an absolute path. It works fine, but did not really get, why all the eclipse examples use a relative path, since it does not use the eclipse workspace, but the eclipse app itself.

Comment: This is because they are building through maven. You could of course TEMP folders also.